# Angular 2 HTTP GET response differs when using in-memory-web-api

Tags: http, angular

I am working on the **Angular 2 Tutorial HTTP** (angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) using the **live example**  (angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/eplnkr.html) as base for my investigations.
This example uses the **Angular in-memory-web-api** (github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) for emulating the web-server.

In file *hero.service.ts* the data array is loaded from server using the following function:

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as Hero)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Analyzing the response object in detail shows, that it has a member *_body* which is an Object. This object has a member *data*, which is an array and contains the heroes, defined in file *in-memory-data.service.ts*.

[image]

Now I want to disable the *Angular in-memory-web-api* and change to a real express server. I comment out the *InMemoryWebApiModule* in the file *app.module.ts* and add some (quick and dirty) additional middleware in the express server.

```
const heroes = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Mr. One'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Mr. Two'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Mr. Three'}
];

function sendDatabaseResponse (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/api/heroes') {
    let response = { };
    response.data = heroes;
    res.json(response);
  }
  else
    next();
}
```

Everything works as expected, but analyzing the *Response* object in *hero.service.ts* shows a different result.
Now the member body is not an object, it's an JSON string containing the data sent by the express server.

[image]

My question. What's the reason for this different response?

Comment: Check headers on both requests, I think it's cause of them. Please add `Content-Type` header with `application/json` value to request in ng2 app if it's missing.

Comment: In both cases the header content-type is `application/json`. In case of express server it is easy to verify, in case of *InMemoryWebApiModule* I add the method *responseInterceptor()* in class *InMemoryDbService* (file *in-memory-data.service.ts*) and look inside *responseOptions*.